# Joomla, a href="#" doesnt work properly

Tags: php, html, joomla

I've made simple form for example in file.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="example"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<a href="#">Link</a>

</body>
<html>
```

Ok. Now when i'm going directly to localhost/file.php then click submit and it goes to  `localhost/file.php?var=example`. Then next i click the Link it goes to `localhost/file.php?var=example#` so its working.

But I'm building component for joomla. I go to my component by alias -> `localhost/joomla/index.php/users_hosts_list`, Now i'm on default view and default layout, then i put the form, that is the example file.php shown above.

When i submit the form it goes to `localhost/joomla/index.php/users_hosts_list?var=example` and i meet the problem. When i click the link, instead of go to `localhost/joomla/index.php/users_hosts_list?var=example#`, this Link delete variable var and it goes to `localhost/joomla/index.php/users_hosts_list#`.

What should i change to fix that?

Comment: what browser are you using? (this may be a browser-specific issue)

Comment: chrome, firefox and ie

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps but Joomla form is getting me to home page with ?var=example#.
Can you write something like this

```
    <?php 
    $post = JRequest::get('post');
    $link = "index.php?option=com_advsearch&view=advsearch&layout=test"; // your Joomla  link
    if($post['var'])
    $newlink = "index.php?option=com_advsearch&view=advsearch&layout=test&var=".$post['var'];

    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $newlink; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="var" value="example"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

   <a href="<?php echo $newlink; ?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Joomla adds a base tag to the head of the page.  I assume that must strip any parameters.

edit: A test tells me that Joomla does strip parameters for that tag.  If you view your source, it will probably have the code:

```
<base href="localhost/joomla/index.php/users_hosts_list">
```

This will cause the link to be localhost/joomla/index.php/users_hosts_list# rather than just a #

When you replace the "#" with the real url it should work.